# MATLAB: Changing the figure height causes children uicontrols to shift in the corresponding direction

Tags: windows, matlab, user-interface

I'm running MATLAB 2012a and am experiencing an issue that I cannot fully resolve without resorting to ugly workarounds. I am currently working on a GUI that will resize the height of the primary figure and children uicontrols upon selecting a value from a popupmenu. The following represents the code used to update the main figure height:

```
% Update the figure height: [x y height width]
Position = get(handles.mainfigure, 'Position');
Position(4) = Position(4) + heightDelta;
set(handles.output, 'Position', Position)
```

However, when the height is changed for the figure, all of the uicontrols move in a corresponding direction. That is, if the height is increased, all children move downward, whereas if the height is decreased, all children move upward. This applies when the units are anything other than 'normalized' (which itself is even more erratic).

While I can easily can around this by shifting the children in the opposite direction by the same delta, is there any way to change the figure height without affecting the position of the uicontrols? This behavior does not occur when changing the height in GUIDE; rather, it only shows up during a callback event.

With 'normalized' units, it causes tables to change height as well, while moving some controls upward and some controls downward. I can't figure out why this is happening. If anyone can shed any light, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The position of children of a figure is relative to the bottom left corner of the figure. Consequently, if you increase the figure height, the uicontrols remain at the same distance from the bottom of the figure, and thus appear to be moving down.

When the units of the uicontrol are normalized, everything, including the space between uicontrols, gets stretched proportionally, which makes uicontrols in the top half appear to move upward, and uicontrols in the bottom half move downward.

From the way positions of graphical objects are defined, there is really not much you can do but to change the positions of all uicontrols.

Comment: That makes sense. I have only recently gotten into MATLAB GUIs (I normally create forms in VB), and I was having a difficult time finding documentation for this behavior. Thank you for the succinct explanation.